# Removing special characters in Drupal Views CSV Data Export

Tags: csv, drupal, drupal-7

I have a CSV file, Data Export from Books and Chapters in Drupal 7.

After exporting to a CSV file, the body of the chapter shows an "Â ", or "`&Acirc;&nbsp;`" in the source code, for each "`&nbsp;`", in the CSV file.  The same thing happens for an apostrophe: "`&rsquo;`" for each apostrophe (').

**An example of the Body in my CSV file:**

```
Â  This book will discuss Title I (General Requirements) and Title IV (Miscellaneous Provisions).Â  The FMLA was effective on August 5, 1993, six months after its passage.Â
```

**The same text in Drupal:**

```
 This book will discuss Title I (General Requirements) and Title IV (Miscellaneous Provisions).  The FMLA was effective on August 5, 1993, six months after its passage.
```

**The same text in my Drupal wysiwyg source code:**

```
&nbsp; This book will discuss Title I (General Requirements) and Title IV (Miscellaneous Provisions).&nbsp; The FMLA was effective on August 5, 1993, six months after its passage.&nbsp;
```

From what I can see, `&nbsp;` turns into "Â  " in the CSV file.

In the Data Export View, I have the Rewrite Results of **Content: Body (Body)** set to strip HTML Tags.  Moreover, I have adding `&nbsp;` to preserve the tag and excluded `&nbsp;` as well.

This is probably a beginner error.  Does anyone know how to remove or replace the results to show the proper text without the odd markup ("Â  ", `&nbsp;`)?

Comment: It's just an htmlentities converstion . When you will import it an htmlentity_decode will by applied and you'll get the right content

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was able to get this working by changing the Character encoding conversion to ASCII in the CSV settings.